# Drawing a project timeline?

Tags: timeline

I am looking for a desktop application I can use for drawing a project timeline. It exists in SmartDraw but I'm guessing a open source alternative exists. I have open project as an alternative to ms project and it does the job, but I need something I can use for drawing a timeline - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the Draw app in open office has stencils for doing timelines.  Can't check now as I don't have it installed at work.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Tom's Planner](http://www.tomsplanner.com/) all the time for instant, easy Gantt charts. You can figure out how it works in seconds. It comes with a bunch of neat features such as inviting read-only users, or exporting the data as Project / Excel readable too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using pen and paper as an alternative. You can draw the timeline really quickly and scan it in as a hard copy. Yet better, I would suggest to keep it up on a whiteboard or as a drawing on a wall to it provides useful point of reference for the team working on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link on how to make timelines and gantt charts w/ excel templates: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/excel-project-management-tracking-templates/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of free timeline drawing apps available. I've used [Timelinemaker](http://www.timelinemaker.com/) (comes with a 7 day free trial).

Answer (score 0):

I know of [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/):  It's GNU Release open source vector drawing program. I've never used it but it looks good.

Comment: Yes, inkscape is very good for vector drawing but might require considerable effort to draw a timeline compared to purpose-build apps.